# How to make Kendo UI grid collapse duplicated rows

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a `Kendo UI grid` that can add new rows.

The added row can have the same id as an existing row, I need to remove old rows that exist.

Wrote code for that, but it doesn't work.

```
function checkSameID(e){
    if(e.type != 'create'){
        return false;
    }
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $.map(e.response, function(row){

        grid.table.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = $('td:first-child', $this).html();
            if(id == row.id){
                var uid = $this.data('uid');
                grid.collapseRow(grid.table.find('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]'));
            }
        });
    });
}

dataSource.bind("requestEnd", checkSameID);
```

Where is my problem?

## UPDATE

DataSource:

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read:  {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                'table':'user','action':'get'}
        },
        update: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrlSave,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST'
        },
        destroy: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrlSave,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
        },
        create: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrlSave,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
        },
        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return {table:'user',action:operation, models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
            }

            return {'table':'user','action':'get'};
        }
    },
    success: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: {
                    editable: false, nullable: true },
                    percent: {
                        type: "number", validation: {
                            required: true}
                    },
                    active: {
                        type: "boolean" },
                        group:{
                            defaultValue: {
                                id:0,name:'Group'},validation: {
                                    required: true }
                        },
                        date:{
                            editable: false, nullable: true },
                            user_name:{
                                editable: false, nullable: true },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error message? When you say you want to "remove old rows that exist", why do you use "collapseRow", which is for collapsing the detail table for a row?

Comment: No, it just doesn't hide the row.

Comment: What about my second question? If you want to remove the row with a given uid, you should use [removeRow](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-removeRow)

Comment: I use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so new row returns with same ID, but it just update, so old row need to hide, not remove.

Comment: So you want both rows to stay in the data source but only one to show? Why?  What are you going to do with the invisible row? Why don't you update the dataItem for the existing row with the data in your updated row?

Comment: There are no both rows, there is only one row in DB. New row has same uniq that row in DB so that row just updated and returns ID of that row. So in my table I have two rows with same ID, but in DB only one. After refresh that row disappear.

Comment: Would you mind to show the DataSource definition? I'd like to see you model definition and check for questions as if `id` is defined as the `id` in the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this may help you,

```
function onSave(e){
    var currentProductName = e.model.ProductName;
    var currentProductID = e.model.ProductID;
    var data = this.dataSource.data();
    for(item in data){
        if(data[item].ProductName == currentProductName &&
           data[item].ProductID != currentProductID){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Duplicates found");
             // here you can delete your Duplicates
             // you had to pass ur UID to 'getByUid' function
             // var dataRow = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
             // $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.remove(dataRow);
        }

    }
}
```

then you can proceed with removing the duplicate.

Refer:
[1.Checking the Kendo Grid for duplicate values](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/checking-the-kendo-grid-for-duplicate-values.aspx)

[2.Deleting grid row by UID programmatically](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/delete-grid-row-by-uid-programmatically.aspx)

[3.Adding And Removing Items In kendo.data.DataSource](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-01-29/adding_and_removing_items_in_kendo_data_datasource.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this is not what I searched but it preventing my problem! Also need to change `e.model` with `e.values`.

Comment: this way not work in IE browser. cannot read elements using "data[item]".

Answer (score 3):

I think you should approach this in a different way - you need to prevent the user from creating a new row with a duplicate id and make him edit the correct row instead ([using validation](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom-validation.html)), or prevent the user from editing the id at all. 
Creating and editing data should be clearly separated.

Answer (score 0):

In IE browser cannot read elemnts like "data[item].ProductName". so use like below.

```
var currentActionCode = e.model.lffaActionCode;
var data = this.dataSource.data();
var i=0;
for(item in data){
    if(e.model.isNew()  && (data[i] != undefined) &&(e.model.uid != data[i].uid) && (data[i].lffaActionCode == currentActionCode.toUpperCase())){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(
        "#errorNotification")
        .data(
                "kendoNotification")
        .show(
                "Duplicate values not allowed.",
                "error");
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```